# How to loop controls in Content Place holder

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnbatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Button btnactual= sender as Button;
    ContentPlaceHolder myContent =
(ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
}
```

How to find controls in the content place holder using `for-each`.I placed my code in `Div tag`
but I am not getting.

Can any one Help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Protected void btnbatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button btnactual= sender as Button;
    ContentPlaceHolder myContent = 
   (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

    foreach (Control ctrl in myContent.FindControl("divBatches").Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == btnactual.ID)
        {
           //blah blah
        }
     }
  }
```

Try This.....